# C++ Vector and Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I'm trying to implement a program which is able to compute a matrix-product.

GOAL: Input v or m and the program automatically computes dot-product, matrix-vector product or matrix product.

The program is working for vectors, and quadratic-matrices but for non-quadratic-matrices the program crashes with.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
```

I'm not sure if the function matrix_input() really is the issue or if my way to enter 2D-Vektors is wrong.

When I input m 2 1 1 2 m 1 2 2 1 the program crashes in the function  matrix_input() because it outputs error-2, error-3 not anymore.
I have noticed that the program crashes because in the second matrix the last row doesn't exist or something similar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


//Checks if input is a matrix or vector
//PRE: Char v or m
//POST: Returns number of the char 1 or 2 or 0 as error
int m_or_v(char m_v) {
  if(m_v=='v')
    return 1;
  else if(m_v=='m')
    return 2;
  assert("error");
  return 0;
}

//Inputs a vector if input was 'v'
//PRE: Takes vector
//POST: Checks length of the vector, inputs values into the vector
void vector_input(vector<int> &vector_v) {
  int row = 0;
  cin >> row;
  int cache = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<row;i++) {
    cin >> cache;
    vector_v.push_back(cache);
  }
}

//Inputs a matrix if input was 'm'
//PRE: Takes matrix
//POST: Checks number row, col and inputs the values into the matrix
void matrix_input(vector<vector<int>> &matrix_m) {
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;
  int cache_m = 0;
  cin >> row;
  cin >> col;
  for(int r = 0;r<row;r++) {
    vector<int> empty = {}; 
    cout << "error-1";
    for(int c = 0;c<col;c++) {
      cin >> cache_m;
      empty.push_back(cache_m);
      cout << "error-2";
    }
    //I believe the program crashes in at this point, because the last row doesn't exist. 
    matrix_m.push_back(empty);
  }
  cout << "error-3";
}

//Computes the dot product if the input were two vectors
void scalar_product(const vector<int> &vector_1,const vector<int> &vector_2) {
  int value = 0;
  if(vector_1.size()==vector_2.size()) {
    for(unsigned long i = 0;i<vector_1.size();i++) {
      value += (vector_1.at(i)*vector_2.at(i));
    }
    cout << "s" << endl;
    cout << value;
  }
  else 
    cout << "error";
}

//Checks if dot product, matrix-vector product or matrix product
int mult_mode(int mode1, int mode2) {
  if(mode1==1&&mode2==2) {
    cout << "error";
    return 0;
  }
  else if(mode1==1&&mode2==1)
    return 1;
  else if((mode1==2&&mode2==1)||(mode1==1&&mode2==2))
    return 2;
  else if(mode1==2&&mode2==2)
    return 3;
  else {
    cout << "error";
    return 0;
  }
}

//Check if Matrix-Vektor Product is possible
bool mvp_valid(const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_1, 
const vector<int> &vector_2) {
  if(matrix_1.at(0).size()==vector_2.size())
    return true;
  return false;
}

//Computes Vector-Matrix product
void mvp_result(const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_1,
const vector<int> &vector_2, vector<int> &result) {
  int cache = 0;
  for(unsigned long row = 0;row<matrix_1.size();row++) {
    for(unsigned long col = 0;col<vector_2.size();col++) {
      cache += matrix_1.at(row).at(col)*vector_2.at(col);
    }
    result.push_back(cache);
    cache = 0;
  }
}

//Outputs a vector
void output_v(vector<int> &vec) {
  cout << "v " << vec.size() << endl;
  for(unsigned long i = 0;i<vec.size();i++) {
    cout << vec.at(i) << " ";
  }
}

//Check if Matrix x Matrix is valid
bool mxm_valid(
const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_1,
const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_2) {
  if(matrix_1.at(0).size()==matrix_2.size())
    return true;
  return false;
}

//Computes the matrix-matrix product
void mxm_result(
const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_1,
const vector<vector<int>> &matrix_2, 
vector<vector<int>> &result_m) {
  
  int cache = 0;
  vector<int> empty;
  
  
  for(unsigned long row = 0;row<matrix_1.size();row++) {
    result_m.push_back(empty);
    for(unsigned long col = 0;col<matrix_2.at(row).size();col++) {
      for(unsigned long row_col = 0;row_col<matrix_2.size();row_col++) {
        cache+=matrix_1.at(row).at(row_col)*matrix_2.at(row_col).at(col);
      }
      result_m.at(row).push_back(cache);
      cache = 0;
    }
  }
}

//Outputs a matrix
void output_m(const vector<vector<int>> &matx) {
  for(unsigned long col = 0;col<matx.size();col++) {
    for(unsigned long row = 0;row<matx.size();row++) {
      cout << matx.at(col).at(row) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

//Outputs the size of the matrix
void size_m(const vector<vector<int>> &matx) {
  cout<<"m "<<matx.size()<<" "<<matx.at(0).size()<<endl;
}

int main() {
  
  char mode_c = ' ';
  int mode1 = 0;
  int mode2 = 0;
  vector<int> vector_1;
  vector<vector<int>> matrix_1;
  vector<int> vector_2;
  vector<vector<int>> matrix_2;
  
  
  //Vector or Matrix Number 1
  cin >> mode_c;
  mode1 = m_or_v(mode_c);
  
  if(mode1==1) {
    vector_input(vector_1);  
  }
  else if(mode1==2) {
    matrix_input(matrix_1);
  }
  //Vector or Matrix Number 2
  cin >> mode_c;
  mode2 = m_or_v(mode_c);
  
  if(mode2==1) {
    vector_input(vector_2);  
  }
  else if(mode2==2) {
    cout << "error-10";
    matrix_input(matrix_2);
    cout << "error-11";
  }

  switch(mult_mode(mode1, mode2)) {
    case 1:
      scalar_product(vector_1,vector_2);
      break;
    case 2:
      if(mvp_valid(matrix_1, vector_2)==true) {
        vector<int> result;
        mvp_result(matrix_1, vector_2, result);
        output_v(result);
      }
      else
        cout << "error";
      break;
    case 3:
      if(mxm_valid(matrix_1, matrix_2)==true) {
        vector<vector<int>> result_m;
        mxm_result(matrix_1, matrix_2, result_m);
        size_m(result_m);
        output_m(result_m);
      }
      else
        cout << "error";
      break;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: The real question to you is:  do you know what that error means?  It means that you are going out-of-bounds when issuing the `at()` call on one of your vectors.  The next step for you is to determine which one of those `at()` calls is throwing the exception.

Comment: Also, that is not a crash.  It is a thrown exception, and it is thrown for a concrete reason.  A crash is when the program abruptedly stops due to something unexpected.

Comment: And [here is a two line program](https://godbolt.org/z/qPrnrETr3) with the same issue.  Do you see something in that tiny program that would cause the exception to be thrown?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is it possible the exception is thrown in the function matrix_input()? Because when executing the program it outputs error-2 but after matrix_m.push_back(empty); the message error-3 isn't displayed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Slowly remove the calls to `at()` by replacing it with `[]`, until there is only one `at()` call left.  It is that call that is throwing the exception.  It doesn't matter what your program's goal is in terms of calculations -- the reason for the exception is that you are going out-of-bounds, and now your job is to find which `at()` call is causing it.  And BTW, that 2-line program throws the exception because the vector has only one element, meaning that the highest index is 0, but the `std::cout` tries to access element index `1`.

Comment: For example: this: `cache += matrix_1.at(row).at(col)*vector_2.at(col);` would be `cache += matrix_1[row][col] * vector_2[col];` if you were to replace the `at()` calls with `[]`.  Do this one at a time until you are left with just one place where `at()` is being called, while at the same time, reproducing the error.

Comment: That error message already tells you exactly what the issue is, now use a debugger to find out where.